# Keep track number of moves of element in array in Shell Sort C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, shellsort

I am having this assignment regarding implementation of Shell Sort in C++. I already manage to get the number of comparison between elements in the array in Shell Sort. However, I can't figure out how to identify the number of moves of the elements after comparison occur. Here is my code for Shell Sort (I get this code from Internet)

```
int shellSort(int arr[], int n) {
int compr = 0;      //indicate num of comparison
cout << endl << "Sorting using Shell Sort..." << endl << endl;
// Start with a big gap, then reduce the gap
for (int gap = n/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2) {
    compr++;        //the gap>0 comparison
    for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1) {
        compr++;    // the i<size comparison
        // add a[i] to the elements that have been gap sorted
        // save a[i] in temp and make a hole at position i
        int temp = arr[i];
        // shift earlier gap-sorted elements up until the correct 
        // location for a[i] is found
        int j;            
        for (j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap) {
            arr[j] = arr[j - gap];
            compr++;    // the j>=gap comparison
            compr++;    // the temp<arr[j-gap] comparison
        }            
        //  put temp (the original a[i]) in its correct location
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}
cout << "Number of Comparison in Array of " << n << " Elements : " << compr << endl;}
```

Hopefully somebody can help me figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make another variable for the count of moves and increment it at the point where a move happens (it is annotated in the comments...)

Comment: sorry Sir, but where is it exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code, where new variable moves indicates the number of moves of elements made during sorting:

```
int shellSort(int arr[], int n) {
    int compr = 0;      //indicate num of comparison
    int moves = 0;
    cout << endl << "Sorting using Shell Sort..." << endl << endl;

    // Start with a big gap, then reduce the gap
    for (int gap = n/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2) {
        compr++;        //the gap>0 comparison

        for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1) {
            compr++;    // the i<size comparison
            // add a[i] to the elements that have been gap sorted
            // save a[i] in temp and make a hole at position i
            int temp = arr[i];
            // shift earlier gap-sorted elements up until the correct
            // location for a[i] is found
            int j;

            for (j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap) {
                arr[j] = arr[j - gap];
                compr++;    // the j>=gap comparison
                compr++;    // the temp<arr[j-gap] comparison
                moves+=2;     // elements are swapped / moved
            }

            //  put temp (the original a[i]) in its correct location
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    cout << "Number of Comparison in Array of " << n << " Elements : " << compr << endl;
    cout << "Number of Moves in Array of " << n << " Elements : " << moves << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Swapping two elements to each other position is assumed to be 2 moves.**

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir! Really appreciate it. :)